# How to fetch string using lua pattern matching

Tags: lua, pattern-matching

below is my string

```
local Amount =[[
Customer Details Net Amount
# Seq Name
Amount NTR
1 CDABCDEFGHIJ00564
0,1234
2 CDABCDEFGHIJ00565
0,0361
3 CDABCDEFGHIJ00566
0,0361
4 CDABCDEFGHIJ00567
0,0722
5 CDABCDEFGHIJ00568
0,0000
6 CDABCDEFGHIJ00569
0,0000
7 CDABCDEFGHIJ00570
0,0000
8 CDABCDEFGHIJ00571
0,7091
9 CDABCDEFGHIJ00572
1,4240
10 CDABCDEFGHIJ00573
0,0361
11 CDABCDEFGHIJ00574
0,5790
12 CDABCDEFGHIJ00575
0,4060
13 CDABCDEFGHIJ00576
0,3610
14 CDABCDEFGHIJ00577
0,6859
15 CDABCDEFGHIJ00578
0,2888
16 CDABCDEFGHIJ00579
0,0000
17 CDABCDEFGHIJ00580
0,0000
18 CDABCDEFGHIJ00581
0,0000
19 CDABCDEFGHIJ00582
0,0000
20 CDABCDEFGHIJ00583
0,0000
21 CDABCDEFGHIJ00584
0,0000
22 CDABCDEFGHIJ00585
0,8978
23 CDABCDEFGHIJ00586
0,0000
24 CDABCDEFGHIJ00587
2,3882
25 CDABCDEFGHIJ00588
0,0000
26 CDABCDEFGHIJ00589
2,0216
27 CDABCDEFGHIJ00590
1,7540
28 CDABCDEFGHIJ00591
0,0000
29 CDABCDEFGHIJ00592
0,0722
30 CDABCDEFGHIJ00593
0,0361
31 CDABCDEFGHIJ00594
0,0000
32 CDABCDEFGHIJ00595
0,0000
Total NAT files
11,9269
Direct inquiries to:
]]
```

by executing the code below

```
local ptrn = '\n([%d%p]+)\n'
for val1, val2 in string.gmatch(Amount, ptrn) do

    print ("val1:=\t" .. (val1 or '').."\tval2:=\t"..(val2 or ''))

end
```

basically from the above string I want to fetch the last 5 digits of the string which is 00564 in val1 and the amount which is 0,1234 in val2 variable, but all this should in one pattern. This is a record, every record is starting with a number like this is 1 record or row

```
1 CDABCDEFGHIJ00564
    0,1234
```

and this is 2nd record or row and so on

```
 2 CDABCDEFGHIJ00565
    0,0361
```

plese help....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that `%d+%s+%a+(%d+)\n%s*([%d,]+)` should do the trick: the first `%d+` will catch the row number, `%s+` to match the white space after. `%a+(%d+)` will match `CDABCDEFGHIJ00592` and capture the digits in the end (no way to specify that you want exactly five digits though). `\n%s*` will match the newline and any white space on the next line and `([%d,]+)` will capture the last number with the comma.